# Assigning Values from a dataframe to another data frame by matching column names to a variable in the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Time = rep(c("Jan 1999", "Feb 1999", "Mar 1999"), each = 3), Country = rep(c("Australia", "Brazil", "Canada"), 3), rep(Group = c("A", "B", "A"), 3), Intercept = NA)
```

and another dataframe with coefficients from a regression where A and B are the Intercepts for the different groups.

```
coeffs <- data.frame(Time = c("Jan 1999", "Feb 1999", "Mar 1999"), A = c(1,2,3), B = c(3,2,1))
```

Now I want to put the Intercepts from the coeffs dataframe into the dataframe's intercept columns. I did this the following way:

```
l <- length(unique(data[,"Country"]))
data[,"Intercept"] <- ifelse(data_1[,"Group_1"] == "A", rep(coeffs_1[,"A"], each = l), rep(coeffs_1[,"B"], each = l))
```

This seems to work well for the 2 groups, but now I need to do the same thing for 7 groups and I don't see how I could generalize the approach above. I guess I could use a 7 level nested ifelse statement or a for loop, but there has to be a more elegant way.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `coeffs` in long format and join with `data` :

```
library(dplyr)

coeffs %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -Time, names_to = 'Group', 
                      values_to = 'Intercept') %>%
  right_join(data, by = c('Time', 'Group'))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
#  Time     Group Intercept Country  
#  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    
#1 Jan 1999 A             1 Australia
#2 Jan 1999 A             1 Canada   
#3 Jan 1999 B             3 Brazil   
#4 Feb 1999 A             2 Australia
#5 Feb 1999 A             2 Canada   
#6 Feb 1999 B             2 Brazil   
#7 Mar 1999 A             3 Australia
#8 Mar 1999 A             3 Canada   
#9 Mar 1999 B             1 Brazil
```

Used this dataframe for `data` :

```
data <- data.frame(Time = rep(c("Jan 1999", "Feb 1999", "Mar 1999"), each = 3),
                   Country = rep(c("Australia", "Brazil", "Canada"), 3), 
                   Group = rep(c("A", "B", "A"), 3))
```